# Video streaming in video player in appcelerator titanium for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, video, azure, titanium

I have just started with iPhone dev on Appcelerator Titanium. I went through the following stuff 
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer. I have tried the media types mentioned but to no avail.  I can  play the sample link procided in the document but can't play the blob link, where i store the video. I am using Azure Media services for storing the video.

Here's the code

```
var videoPlayer = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
    url:'http://101appstest1.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/6a7bde21-ebb1-4c5e-8dc5-b4b107b41de0/BigBuckBunny.ism/Manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)',
    media:'Blob',
    top : '120px',
    autoplay : true,
    backgroundColor : 'blue',
    height : 300,
    width : 300,
    mediaControlStyle : Ti.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_FULLSCREEN,
    scalingMode : Ti.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT,
    });


    self.add(videoPlayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hemant I just tired your URL (HLS v4), but it returned me a 404. I suggest the following for your debugging reference:

1. If you are using dynamic packaging, please make sure you have one streaming Reserved Unit turned on. You could adjust that through Portal, under Media Services -> Origin tab.
2. If you packaged your media file through portal (Static packaged HLS content), please try to see whether you could playback the content through a native Safari Browser.
3. Currently, we support HLS v4 and V3 through dynamic packaging (Please read my blog post here: http://mingfeiy.com/android-hls-playback-via-azure-media-services). Maybe you are trying to deliver V4 to a browser that doesn't support V4?